# How to format header in Excel worksheet using AppleScript

Tags: applescript, ms-office, font

Here is the VBA code for customizing the font, font size, and stylizing the headers and footers in an Excel spreadsheet:

```
'With sht.PageSetup
            '.CenterHeader = "&R&""Consolas""&KFFFF00" & sht.Name
            '.PrintArea = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastrow, lastcol)).Address
'End With
```

How to do I convert this to AppleScript? I tried the following:

```
tell application id "com.microsoft.Excel"
    set screen updating to false
    set wb to active workbook
    set wsName to the name of the active sheet of wb
    repeat with ctr from 1 to the count of worksheets in wb
        log ctr
        set sName to (the name of worksheet ctr of wb)
        select worksheet sName
        tell page setup object of active sheet
            set center header to sName
            --.CenterHeader = "&R&""Consolas""&KFFFF00" & sht.Name
            -- set center header to "&R&""Consolas""&KFFFF00" & sName
        end tell
    end repeat
    
    save wb
    select worksheet wsName -- return to the original active sheet
    set screen updating to true
    
end tell
```

but I need assistance in this line:

`– set center header to "&R&""Consolas""&KFFFF00" & sName`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    set center header to "&R&\"Consolas,Regular\"&KFFFF00&A"
```

A couple of comments…

`center header` can also be used to return the header settings. So when trying to determine the correct syntax, you can always set them manually and then run something like this.

```
tell page setup object of active sheet
    get center header
end tell
```

It will return this, which you can then use in your script.

```
"&R&\"Consolas,Regular\"&KFFFF00&A"
```

Note that the font requires quotes around it — otherwise you would be inserting the '&C' code — and those must be escaped. Also, the '&A' code will insert the sheet name, so you shouldn't have to use the sName variable. Finally, I get flaky behaviour from the '&R' code, which seems to set the right header instead. Maybe it's a bug, maybe it's only in excel 2011. Who can say.

Hope this helps.

Addendum:

By the way, the proper way to make a sheet active is to `activate object` it, like so:

```
tell application id "com.microsoft.Excel"
    activate
    
    set wb to active workbook
    set wsName to the name of the active sheet of wb
    delay 2
    activate object worksheet 4
    delay 2
    activate object worksheet wsName
end tell
```

Comment: This is very helpful. I got my desired header with set center header to "&C" & "&KFF0000&\"Consolas\"" & sName. Have noted the comment on &A for sheet name as well.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/workbooks-and-worksheets/formatting-and-vba-codes-for-headers-and-footers. -- this gives all header and footer options and the code thereof.

Comment: &KFFFF00 -- &K concatenated with HEX code

Comment: Glad to hear it. Please consider accepting and/or a vote on the answer. Thanks.

Comment: I was wondering about the &K code. I rely on the Excel 2004 applescript document, which does not include it. But when I set the colour manually and then retrieved the coding, it was included.